# Scroll function script makes the tab at top of browser spin and show it's still loading

Tags: javascript, wordpress

When I add this script my tab keeps spinning like the page is still loading.  Is there something I have wrong in this script that would make it do that?

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(document).on('scroll', function () {
            $('.logo img').toggleClass('small', $(document).scrollTop() >= 10);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Sometimes it loads fine but it seems like after a few page loads it starts spinning again and doesn't stop until I click the X (should be browser refresh but shows X because it's still loading) to stop loading.

Here is the dev site - https://perkedup.tfm-dev.com/

Comment: The code looks good, it should not make your tab loading. also i entered to the link and i dont have the same issue, did you try to check with different browser?

Comment: Thank you Elna for checking!  I tried in Chrome and your right it was fine.  I don't know why Firefox keeps doing this.